# Adding a substring in powershell

Tags: json, powershell, object

I import a csv file in powershell with this code:

```
import-csv "input.csv" | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content -Path "output.json"
```

My output:

```
{
 "users": [
     {
       "firstName": "name1",
       "lastName": "lastname1",
     }
     {
       "firstName": "name2",
       "lastName": "lastname2",
     }
}
```

The csv file look like this:

```
firstname,lastname
name1,lastname1
name2,lastname2
```

But I need to ad a extra column called "roles" with sub content (I dont know what its called). It should be after lastname, but still part of the users object and in every entry.

Need this output

```
  {
 "users": [
     {
       "firstName": "name1",
       "lastName": "lastname1"
       "roles:" ["role1", "role2"]
     }
     {
       "firstName": "name2",
       "lastName": "lastname2",
       "roles:" ["role1", "role2"]
     }
}
```

New output

```
"Roles":  {
  "value":  [
    "Role1",
    "Role2"
    ],
  "Count":  2
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add it before you convert it to JSON? Where do you get the values for the new column?

Comment: Although it is not hard to add an extra column to the csv data, PowerShell would have no idea what to put in it that specifies the actual role per user.. Woud be simpler if you just add that to the CSV

Comment: The value of the extra column is just static data. My problem is how to add these kind of square brackets like a multidimensional array. It is also fine if its possible to add the data direct in the csv file.

Comment: Your JSON syntax output is wrong

Comment: Where is your csv that produces that json? What does it look like? Because the CSV you show does not produce the output you show.

Comment: Your CSV wont produce that JSON you have in your example... (and the JSON syntax is still not valid). Try parsing it in https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Do you mean that you currently have the data in CSV, but would like to migrate it to a structured format like JSON? Then you will have to stay in a structured format, there is no (easy parsable) way to save it back to a flat format as CSV.

Answer (score 1):

```
@'
firstname,lastname
name1,lastname1
name2,lastname2
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Select-Object -Property *,@{Name = 'Roles';Expression= {@('Role1','Role2')}} |
        ConvertTo-Json
```

... produces this output:

```
[
  {
    "firstname": "name1",   
    "lastname": "lastname1",
    "Roles": [
      "Role1",
      "Role2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "firstname": "name2",   
    "lastname": "lastname2",
    "Roles": [
      "Role1",
      "Role2"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: It looks good but the staticdata looks just like the csv data. It needs to be a object in a object. The roles has to look like the "users"

Comment: ?? What ?? ... are you sure you understood how JSON works?

Comment: I  assume what @Stefan is looking for is for the `"roles"` property value to be an _array_; e.g., `"roles": [ "role1", "role2" ]`

Comment: @mklement0 But that can't be saved as a plain CSV...

Comment: Indeed, @Dennis - a custom array representation embedded in a single string that the importer needs to be aware of will have to be used.

Comment: P.S., @Dennis: What my previous comment states will be necessary if the roles are be added _to the CSV file_, but I'm unclear on whether that's actually needed; if the target format is JSON, and the role information can be added _dynamically_, the problem may not arise.

Comment: It dont has to be in the csv file. It is fine to add it to the object after the csv file is loaded. I have updated my question with the output I trying to get.

Comment: On my output I get "value: Role1" not only "Role1" and amount of roles with a "count"

Comment: What do you get when you run my code example exactly how I posted it?

Comment: Look at my new output (just pasted the roles). You can see that it both shows "value" and count. Its almost look good

Comment: @Stefan You may swith to PowerShell v7.x to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Add-Member is a somewhat slow method but viable...

```
$json = ConvertFrom-Json @'
{
    "users": [{
            "firstName": "name1",
            "lastName": "lastname1"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "name2",
            "lastName": "lastname2"
        }
    ]
}
'@
 
$json.users | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Roles -Value 'empty'

$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output

```
{
    "users": [{
            "firstName": "name1",
            "lastName": "lastname1",
            "Roles": "empty"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "name2",
            "lastName": "lastname2",
            "Roles": "empty"
        }
    ]
}
```

But we are leaning towards you are looking for something like this instead...

```
$json | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name roles -Value @('role1','role2')
```

Output

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "firstName": "name1",
      "lastName": "lastname1"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "name2",
      "lastName": "lastname2"
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
    "role1",
    "role2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Dennis. The roles has to be after the lastname. It has to be in the list twice.

Comment: You mean as in the first Output above when adding to $json.users? Could you provide a complete example in your question of the desired out come, please?